# MySQL 5.6.15 - “WHERE `DATE` >={ts '2013-12-01 00:00:00'}” producing an unreliably different result to “WHERE `DATE` >='2013-12-01 00:00:00'”?

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

As title says, recently upgraded to `MySQL 5.6.15` - now having an issue where the query

```
WHERE `DATE` >={ts '2013-12-01 00:00:00'}
```

brings back an unreliably different (i.e. sometimes it's the same, sometimes it's not, with no difference in the query whatsoever - just running at different times) result to:

```
WHERE `DATE` >='2013-12-01 00:00:00'
```

Any ideas?

I am at my wits end with this one- nobody else seems to have this issue after searching for hours on hours..

Comment: Can you paste exact query ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table` with the above where clause. Unfortunately, I am unable to post exact table structure - but the `{ ts` literal is definitely the cause of the issue.

Comment: Do you have frequent inserts/deletes in table ?

Comment: Can you post sample existing records and resulting differences.

Comment: No - this database is completely static. I've checked the sample and resulting differences...it's a complete mix of dates and times that are missed out - there's no similarity between them

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589296/mysql-not-generating-correct-results-using-odbc-date-parameter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would "WHERE \`DATE\` >={ts '2013-12-01 00:00:00'}" produce a different result to "WHERE \`DATE\` >='2013-12-01 00:00:00'"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284480/why-would-where-date-ts-2013-12-01-000000-produce-a-different-result)